# Mysql Rlike condition

Tags: mysql, rlike

I have a table name `company`

```
Company  |  category_id
NEC      |     cg17,cg19,cg23
Huawei   |     cg55,cg17,cg25
```

Which I query like this:

```
select * from company
where category_id RLIKE '^cg17,cg19'
```

with result:

```
Company  |  category_id
NEC      |  cg17,cg19,cg23
```

but when I query like this:

```
select * from company
where category_id RLIKE '^cg17,cg23'
```

I get no rows, but I want company "NEC", because NEC has category_id 
"cg17,cg19,cg23"

How to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way, if your categories are always in order and don't include categories with more than 2 digits:

```
select * from company
where category_id LIKE 'cg17%cg23'
```

A better way IMHO, which treats the field as a proper CSV value:

```
select * from company
where FIND_IN_SET('cg17', category_id) > 0
and FIND_IN_SET('cg23', category_id) > 0
```